# COPY FROM says 'No records inserted in 90 seconds', but records were indeed inserted

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh, cassandra-3.0

I have two .csv files that I generated using the same simple python script. Both have 6 columns, one has 365 rows and the other, 120. When I try to `copy from` the larger file, it works as expected, but when I do the same with the smaller one, I get:

```
No records inserted in 90 seconds, aborting
```

However when I do a `select` on the table, I see that actually some rows were added. This happened to a newly created table, regardless of which file I try import first.

Has anyone had this problem before? Anyone knows what's causing this?

I'm using `cqlsh` version 5.0.1, Cassandra 3.11.0, CQL spec 3.4.4, Ubuntu 16.04.

The table:

```
create table rated_skills (  primary_group varchar, secondary_group varchar, tertiary_group varchar, skill varchar, person varchar, rating int, primary key ((primary_group), skill, rating, person)) with clustering order by (skill desc, rating desc);
```

The copy command:

```
copy rated_skills (primary_group, secondary_group, tertiary_group, skill, person, rating) from 'methodologies_output.csv';
```

The csv that doesn't work: [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12SaSR9LbGhSOCj2tbfg4B3lTLILP7aKTbpufL0iBP5c/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I am running into the same problem while trying to import large datasets, it gives this error at about the last 0.5% of the remaining rows. Have you been able to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

My guess on why your solution doesn't work is probably due to, that you are using column names such as 'primary' which of course is a reserved word in cql.

I couldn't perform the copy when my column names was the same as yours, after I changed the first three columns, it worked perfectly fine:

```
create table rated_skills (group1 varchar, group2 varchar, group3 varchar, skill varchar, person varchar, rating int, primary key ((group1), skill, rating, person)) with clustering order by (skill desc, rating desc)
```

And Copy from *.csv

```
copy 'keyspace'.rated_skills (group1, group2, group3, skill, person,rating) from 'csv.csv';
```

Furthermore remember if your work with a huge data set you can use sstable writer to write and sstableloader to load data faster.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with the this message being shown when using `COPY` to import large `csv` files. In my case however the process didn't import any rows into the table.

The table in question has some column which use `UDT`s which I believe decreases the performance drastically so that it runs into the timeout.

I was able to get around this problem by using parameters on `COPY`, setting the `CHUNKSIZE` and `NUMPROCESSES` to lower values than the default values, which are `1000` and `16` respectively.

The command I used was `COPY mytable FROM 'mytable.csv' USING HEADER=TRUE AND CHUNKSIZE=50 AND NUMPROCESSES=4`. Without the two extra parameters I was not able to import the file.

You can find the different parameters for `COPY` [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh_commands/cqlshCopy.html).